# Ошибка 'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and 'System.Numerics.Vector2'

Tags: c#, unity3d

`Assets/Scripts/New_wall.cs(10,5): error CS0104: 'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and 'System.Numerics.Vector2'` помогите

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;


public class New_wall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8f;
    Vector2 direction;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            direction = Vector2.up;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            direction = Vector2.down;
        }
        else
        {
            direction = Vector2.zero;
        }
        if (direction.x * direction.x + direction.y * direction.y != 0)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(direction * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добрый день проблема в том что проект не хочет запускаться и ругаться на вектора.Удалил систем намераклс но не работает.

Comment: уберите `using System.Numerics;`, объясните, что значит "не работает", отредактируйте вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у тебя подключено два пространства имён: System.Numerics и UnityEngine. В каждом из них есть Vector2, и компилятор не знает какой ты хочешь использовать.

На будущее, если компилятор выдаёт ошибку, прежде чем писать на форум, её нужно загуглить. У тебя это CS0104, просто вводишь в поиск **C# CS0104** и скорее всего найдёшь ответ в чём проблема.

Comment: А еще можно даже не вводить, а скопировать текст ошибки и вставить...

Comment: @МаксимФисман это уже для middle разработчиков.